# Estimate Maximum and Minimum of Integral $I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2-x^3}}$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Estimate Maximum and Minimum of Integral $$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x^2-x^3}}$$

My try: we have By Mean value Theorem of Integration , if $f(x)$ is Continuous with Infimum and Supremum as $m$ and $M$ Then

$$m(b-a) \lt \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx \lt M(b-a)$$

It Means we need to find Infimum and Supremum of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2-x^3}}$ in $\left[0 \:\:, 1\: \right]$

Now should we use differentiation to find $m$ and $M$ or is there any other way to estimate?

Comment: The integrand being monotone, there is no need to differentiate.

Comment: I don't understand. Since the integral will give answer as some unique real number( specifically "$0.5479$") then where does "minimum" and "maximum" of integral come from

Comment: I guess the intended question is *produce some sharp bounds for the following (elliptic) integral*, but until that is clarified and some attempt is added, I am closing the question.

Comment: Additionally, the given integral is pretty clearly bounded between $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}$, since $4-x^2-x^3$ is bounded between $4-x^2$ and $4-2x^2$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2-x^3}}$ is increasing for $0\leq x\leq 1$, we have
$$\frac 12=f(0)\leq f(x)\leq f(1)=\frac{\sqrt 2}2$$
for all $x\in [0,1]$.
Consequently,
$$\frac 12\leq\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2-x^3}}\mathrm dx\leq\frac{\sqrt 2}2$$

Comment: I think it's increasing on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Botond: Fixed, thanks